# Large Unused Space After Table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am writing a report in a two-column format. I had a table that uses more than half the length of a page and I have expanded the table over both columns. However, at the end of the table I get a large unused space after the table and my text begins from the next page.

```
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}}
        Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 & Data 4
        \hline
        ..........
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test Table}
    \label{table9}
\end{table*}
```

What can be the reason for such space? I have attached the screenshot[image: screenshot]

Comment: the data row should be above `\end tabular`

Comment: Yeah, I just saw this. It is in the original document. I just missed it here

Comment: I am playing with \vspace{} now. If I use \vspace{-3.14em} the first line of text overlaps with caption. However, if I use \vspace{-3.13em}, the text goes to the next page!

Comment: With the information you provided so far, the issue is unfortunately not reproducible `\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}}
        Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 & Data 4\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test Table}
    \label{table9}
\end{table*}
\lipsum
\end{document}` for example works perfectly finde and no large space below the table occurs.

Comment: The reason for the large space is most likely in the code you did not include. Therefore, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question. With this, others can reproduce the output you get.